# Solving $3(xyy'-y^2)\cos(-1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})=2x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I am trying to solve $3(xyy'-y^2)\cos(-1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})=2x^2$

And I am making it in the form of

$$y'=\frac{2x^2}{\cos(\frac{y^2}{x^2}-1)3xy}$$ + y/x

So it could look like a linear differential equation, but I can't seem to make it in such form. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

$$3y\dfrac{xy'-y}{x^2}\cos\left(-1+\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)^2\right)=2$$
$$2\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)'\cos\left(-1+\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)^2\right)=\left(\dfrac{4}{3x}\right)$$
$$\sin\left(-1+\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)^2\right)=\dfrac{4}{3}\ln x+C$$

Comment: how do you get from the second row to the third ?

Comment: $(\sin u)'=u'\cos u$.

Comment: this is genius :) . and now i am solving it for y(x) ?. Couse i am getting some really difficult stuff.

Comment: Find $y(x)$ now.